# Copying large files from SSD ext4 to external USB3 ext4 drive very slow

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10, installed on a 480 GB Western Digital Green SSD drive. When I copy large video files (> 2 GB or so) to a 1 TB Seagate HDD, formatted as ext4, which is connected to USB3 or USB2 (doesn't matter which) I get copying speeds when writing to the external 1 TB HDD, of only around 1 MB/s. The same external HDD, when formatted as NTFS gives me copying speeds of 70 to 90 MB/s when on Windows 10.

What can I do to increase the write speeds to the external 1 TB Seagate HDD when it is formatted in ext4 and used in Ubuntu 20.10?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried out some changes to the system and the external HDD and things have improved.

1. My Ubuntu 20.10 installation did not have a swap partition, so I added a 5 GB permanent swap partition in the internal SSD where Ubuntu is installed.
2. I changed the partition table in the external 1 TB Seagate external HDD from "msdos" to "gpt" by using Gparted to partition and format the external HDD.

Then I tried out the copy performance by copying a 6.5 GB file from the SSD to the external HDD using Grsync and Grsync copied the file to the external HDD at more then 100 MB/sec.

I ran a benchmark on the external HDD from the "Disks" application and the performance is much better. I used the USB3 port to connect the external HDD for all the above activities.

[image: Benchmark test]

I hope this helps.